# What does [projects NO-HEAD] in STS's Servers folder means?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

When I start my STS (Spring Tool Suite) it shows me beside the Servers/ folder:

```
[projects NO-HEAD]
```

and a question mark icon at the folder (which seems to be a problem...)

What does this means?

If this is an issue, how can I fix it?

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have a project directory which I link to a remote repository (self hosted Gitlab) but somehow when I launch the project in STS, it didn't automatically / detect my git configuration.

**My solution [in STS] :**

1. Right click on the project
2. Select Team > Share Project
3. Check the check box 'use or create repository in parent folder or project
4. Check the check box with '.git'